# Shortest Path in a graph

Tags: c++, algorithm, dijkstra, shortest-path, bellman-ford

My graph is implemented in the following way:

```
struct node{
    string ID;
    vector<string> neighbors;

}

struct graph{
    vector<string> nodes;
}
```

nodes is a vector of nodes. Each node contains its ID and a vector of all of its neighbor's (Nodes it is pointing to) IDs

Is there a way I can apply Dijkstra's algorithm or Bellman-Ford to find the shortest path between two nodes? Find a duplicate cycle? How would I do that?

EDIT: sturcts were accidental named the same.

Comment: If that is an adjacency list you have - yes, it is possible.

Comment: I don't think its an adjacency list, I clarified my code.

Comment: Both your structs have the same name. Do you have a vector of `node` somewhere or something similar? Why don't you use a `vector<node*>` instead of `vector<string>` for neighbors?

Comment: how do you retrieve a node, do you have a global map of id->node?

Comment: Looking up elements will waste time with this kind of mapping. It should be easy to construct an adjacency list of `vector<node*>` as @Nabla suggested.

Comment: with hashtable the lookup should be O(1)

Comment: This sounds like a homework problem; please show us your attempt?

Comment: Sorry fixed the structs. Its not a HW problem. My main references are the Dijkstra and Bellman-Ford wikipedia articles but I'm having trouble converting the psudo code to match my problem set.

Comment: @dj3000 You still haven't answered the most important question: Where are the `node` instances and why do you reference nodes by a string instead of the node address/pointer?

Comment: @Nabla I reference nodes by a string to match the payload of each node. I suppose it would have made more sense to create the neighbors vector as vector<node*>, but I'm nto too worried about the overhead for this. The node instances are in the vector nodes in the graph struct. I hope this clarifies my question more?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention anything about the edge weight.

Dijkstra algorithm works if you don't have a negative edge weight.

Bellman-ford algorithm works if you don't have a negative cycle. But you can also use Bellman-Ford algorithm to check if you have a negative cycle.

If it's a weightless edged-graph, you can just use BFS.